# Question about infinite-dimensional BM

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, brownian-motion

Suppose we are given an $L^2(\mathcal{D})$-valued Brownian motion $W_t$ defined by
$$W_t:=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{\sigma_k}W_t^k\phi_k(x),$$
where $\mathcal{D}$ is bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^d$, $\{\phi_k(x)\}$ forms the complete orthogonal basis of $L^2(\mathcal{D})$, $\{W_t^k\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}^{+}}$ are mutually independent one-dimensional standard BM, and $\sigma_k$ satisfies
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sigma_k<\infty.$$

Is it possible that

$$\lim_{k\to \infty}\sup_{t\geq 0}(-\Lambda t+\sqrt{\sigma_k}W^k_t)=0,\ \mathbb{P}-a.s.,$$

where $\Lambda$ is an given positive number?

Comment: the sup gives independent exponential r.v.'s with known parameters

Answer (score 2):

I have not done the computation, but shouldn't you be able to compute 
$P(\sup_{t\geq 0}(-\Lambda t+\sqrt{\sigma_k}W_t^k)\geq a)$ for each fixed $a$ and $k$, then apply Borel-Cantelli?

Comment: That contributes to convergence in probability only but not P-a.s.

Comment: But Borel cantelli should tell you that the probability that $\sup_{t\geq 0}(-\Lambda t+\sqrt{\sigma_k}W_t^k)\geq a$ happen for infinitely many $k$ is 0, which is just a.s. convergence, right? Isn't your $W^k_t$ independent?

Comment: Borel Cantelli give you the probability of $\limsup$ rather than $\lim$ to be zero, which implies that you could only find a subsequence which converges to zero $\mathbb{P}-a.s.$....

Comment: $\mathbb{P}$-a.s. Convergence of the subsequence is not what I want for...